# Overlapping or carry over skill term

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for skills where learning Skill A overlaps or carries over to Skill B?

I.E. An Olympic class Gymnast could carry over those skills and become a very good diver or a very good dancer.

Comment: What is wrong with *carries over*?

Answer (score 5):

I think the term you are looking for is "transferable" or "**transferable skill**".

*"His graceful composure as a gymnast is transferable to his diving hobby."*

*"Somersaulting is a transferable skill between diving and gymastics."*

**Transferable skills** — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transferable-skills)

> *noun plural* Skills used in one job or career that can also be used in another.
>
> *"Leadership is a highly transferable skill."*